# Android Studio - Cursor.getString() throwing exception

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, cursor

I'm new to Android Studio and this is my first application in general where I'm working with database connectivity, so I may just be fundamentally misunderstanding how the cursor works.

I'm querying my database, and tests show that the query is successful, specifically the getCount() method returns 2 as the number of rows the cursor object contains. However when I call the getString() method it throws an exception instead of returning the column data.

Anything pop out right away that could be wrong with this code?

```
    public void GetFacts(View v) {

    Cursor cursor = database.query(ExternalDbOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            null, "valueRange = 'MEDIUM'", null, null, null, null);

    // Log number of rows from query
    Log.d("CursorTest", "Row count: " + cursor.getCount());

    try {
        // get data from "factName" column of database
        String columnName = cursor.getColumnName(0);
        Log.d("CursorTest", "Column Name: " + columnName);

        String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));

    } catch(Exception e) {
        // Log exception thrown
        Log.d("CursorTest", "Error getting data: " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

**And the log gives me the following:**

> D/CursorTest: Row count: 2
>
> D/CursorTest: Column Name: factName
>
> D/CursorTest: Error getting data: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2

Comment: When asking a question about an exception, or logging one, make sure to report the **type** of the exception, such as CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException, not just the exception's message. This is the most critical information for figuring out what went wrong. You can find it out easily by adding the exception (your `e` parameter) as a third parameter to the `Log.d()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to move the cursor to the first position first example

```
cursor.moveToPosition(0);
```

Comment: I did up vote, but they will not display my feedback until I reach 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Your cursor initializes at index -1. You need to call [moveToNext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29) or [moveToPosition(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition%28int%29) to set it to a position with data in it.